# Grant ForceChangePW privilege to a specific user

Tags: active-directory

I'm trying to grant ForceChangePW privilege to a non-administrator user, as stated here:

[image]

So in the delegation of control wizard I've checked the following tasks

[image]

Then on another computer I logged in as that user, when I try to modify the password of a Domain Admin user, e.g `net user XXX newpassword /domain`

I still get Access Denied error

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Members of protected groups, such as Domain Admins, have the security permissions (ACL) reset every hour. Even if you delegate permissions to another security principal, it will not apply to protected users.

AdminSDHolder, Protected Groups and SDPROP
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2009.09.sdadminholder.aspx

Comment: Yep, this is the answer.